# Auto refresh 2 images on Wordpress page using Javascript

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I am trying to auto refresh 2 images that come from a couple of old webcams and are embedded in a Wordpress page.  The cams save an image every 60 seconds into a specific folder and overwrite the previous images with the exact same name.

The code I am trying to use works perfectly for one image but if used for both images the second image overwrites the first.  This code is added into a code block in a page builder.  I was trying to use the code twice in separate columns, and yes I was using the different/correct URL's for each.

How can I have both of the images auto reload every 60 seconds?

Thanks in advance.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// <![CDATA[
var refreshrate = 60;          // seconds between refresh
var image       = "[Image URL]";    // image name
var imgwidth    = 640;        // image width
var imgheight   = 480;        // image height
var imgalt      = "WebCam Image";
var imgtitle    = "header=[WebCam Image] body=[WebCam Image Automatically Updated Every 30 Seconds] delay=[1000]";
function refresh() { document.images["pic"].src = image + "?" + new Date(); setTimeout('refresh()', refreshrate * 1000); }
document.write('<img src="' + image + '" alt="' + imgalt + '" title="' + imgtitle + '" name="pic" id="pic" width="' + imgwidth + '" height="' + imgheight + '" style="border: none;" />');
if(document.images)window.onload=refresh;
// ]]>
</script>
```

Comment: It woube be better if we could see the html, please provide a [mcve], you should also avoid document.write

Comment: The page in question I'm trying to make this work on is here:  http://www.zfsinc.com/webcam/

Sorry, I didn't know if posting a direct link was appropriate, I'm new here.  Anything else you need?